# How does the study of 'schoolmen' help in improving our distinguishing skills?

Tags: meaning, essays, francis-bacon

I have been reading the short essay "[Of Studies](https://englishliterature.net/francis-bacon/of-studies)" by Sir Francis Bacon. I couldn't understand the meaning of this sentence:

> If his wit be not apt to distinguish or find differences, let him study the Schoolmen, for they are *cymini sectores*.

Please do explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Schoolmen* refers to the [scholastics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism), mediæval philosophers such as  [William of Ockham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_of_Ockham) and [Thomas Aquinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Aquinas).  The scholastics dominated European intellectual life in the twelfth and thirteenth centuries. The method they used to analyze philosophical and theological concepts was [dialectical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectic): they examined opposing points of view and reconciled the contradictions through reasoned argument. Scholastic reasoning requires knowing exactly what one is reasoning *about*, and such exactitude entails fine distinctions. The precision and clarity with which the scholastics define the terms of their arguments can come across as hair-splitting.

Bacon therefore says that someone who is having trouble "distinguishing or finding differences" should study the scholastics, because they are "*cymini sectores*," literally "splitters of cumin seeds." By seeing how the schoolmen distinguish one term from another, the student can learn the art of differentiating clearly between related concepts.